# "PHP Startup: odbtp: Unable to initialize module" module API doesn't match

Tags: php

I need to enable a module installed on my system. I have installed PHP 5.4 from ondrej's repository couple of months ago ago and now I have compiled ODBTP module from the source.

Unfortunately, if only I enable this module I receive an error causing all the PHP scripts failure:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: odbtp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I think I understand what it's trying to tell me, I wanted to compile PHP from source, so that it would have matching version of API, however I can't find the source for my version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- You have compiled ODBTP with old PHP.  Please check that you have correct version of php5-dev package installed and you don't have any extra (old) installation of PHP on your system
- Or you have compiled ODBTP module before you have upgraded your system PHP to 5.4
- Or the ODBTP build system is broken (less likely)

Anyway it's not the PHP you need to recompile, but the ODBTP module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ondrej, I know I have compiled ODBTP with older PHP version, that's what the warning is telling me. I have compiled the module after I have upgraded my PHP to 5.4. As far as I have found out - my PHP is in version 5.4.17, but my php5-dev stayed on version 5.3...

Comment: @khartvin Then upgrade php5-dev to 5.4.x and recompile ODBTP, and you should be fine.

Comment: I have already done it, but no change... I've got a gut feeling that somewhere on the system remained some files from the previous installation of PHP, but I have no idea, where they may be linked... php-config shows me only information about the 5.4 version that is correct.

Comment: Try to find all instances of the ODBTP extension and delete it before you compile&install the new one.

Comment: everytime I try installing ODBTP, I remove all previous compilations.